# What protocol and port does npm use?

Tags: npm, npm-install, node-modules

When I run

```
npm install
```

What protocol and port does it use for fetching the node_modules folder files?

I didn't find an answer by searching here or on Google

Comment: You can run npm install --verbose and see

Answer (score 13):

When npm installs you project dependencies, it does requests to its registry, which is at https://registry.npmjs.org, so, the answer to your question is HTTPS and 443. HTTP unencrypted web traffic is port 80, HTTPS encrypted traffic is used by most reputable sites and services thus port 443.

Answer (score 3):

I was curious about the same thing as well and fell on your question. Unfortunately, not really answered (at least to my satisfaction). So I did a bit more digging and found the following (if it helps).

**NPM Wikipedia**

If you read the NPM Wikipedia page, it states the following:

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)

> npm is written entirely in JavaScript and was developed by Isaac Z.
> Schlueter as a result of having "seen module packaging done terribly"
> and with inspiration from other similar projects such as PEAR (PHP)
> and CPAN (Perl).
>
> npm consists of a command line client that interacts with a remote
> registry. It allows users to consume and distribute JavaScript modules
> that are available in the registry. **Packages in the registry are
> in CommonJS format** and include a metadata file in JSON format.

If you go to CommonJS Wikipedia:

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS

> CommonJS is a project with the goal to establish conventions on the
> module ecosystem for JavaScript outside of the web browser.

**Specifications**

The list of specifications includes

- Modules/1.0 (Superseded by Modules/1.1)
- Modules/1.1
- Modules/1.1.1
- Packages/1.0
- System/1.0

But no link or refernces to each of the specifications (unfortunately). So not much information of value here.

If you Google 'Modules/1.1.1 specification' you get this Wiki page:

https://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1.1

But it seems to be more focused on the client side of things and not the server side (or registry).

A Google search for 'System/1.0 specification' yeilds nothing.

A Google search for 'Packages/1.0 specifications' on the other falls on this Wiki page:

https://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Packages/1.1

And now we seem to be on to something interesting (you'll see why shortly)!

Per @Ankur's comment in the post, if you use the `--verbose` flag, which I did, and got the following:

`npm install --verbose express`

Here is the ouput (partial):

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '--verbose',
npm verb cli   'express'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@6.14.15
npm info using node@v14.18.1
npm verb npm-session 0c3dc38af8d96c85
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express 638ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-4.18.2.tgz 15ms (from cache)
npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 720ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 0ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 1ms
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/accepts 334ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/array-flatten 354ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/content-disposition 385ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/content-type 412ms
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-html 89ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/etag 85ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/encodeurl 438ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser 454ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/content-type/-/content-type-1.0.5.tgz 59ms
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/finalhandler 89ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug 478ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie 493ms (from cache)
```

*Note: Output goes on for hundreds of lines longer (but it's not all that important).*

So what's interesting here are a few things:

On the 12th line, you'll notice that it establishes an `https` connection with the registry (at `https://registry.npmjs.org/express`), where the module being installed (`express`) is the first path item.

You can try it for yourself with your browser:

https://registry.npmjs.org/express

You'll get a JSON output!

*Tip: Install a JSON extension for your browser if you want to view it in a structured manner and optionally color coded.*

Here is a screenshot of my output:

[image]

You'll notice a few obvious important module properties, but what's interesting is the `dist-tags` property. It seems to indicate the `latest` and the `next` version numbers.

Why is the `latest` important? Well because if you go back to the `npm` output above, you'll notice that the very next https GET that is made to the NPM repository is:

https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-4.18.2.tgz

Where you have the `4.18.2` version number (as proposed by the `latest` property).

Calling the above URL from your browser will actually download the `express` module (in `tgz` format) from the NPM repository.

You'll notice that it is followed by a series of additional HTTPS calls:

```
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/accepts 334ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/array-flatten 354ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/content-disposition 385ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/content-type 412ms
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-html 89ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/etag 85ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/encodeurl 438ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser 454ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/content-type/-/content-type-1.0.5.tgz 59ms
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/finalhandler 89ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug 478ms (from cache)
```

These would seem to be the **dependencies** for the `express` module. What is not clear (at the moment, more research will be needed on my part), is if this list is obtained from the `tgz` module package itself (in the `package.json` file), OR from the original HTTPS call (from the `versions > 4.18.2 > dependencies` list. I'm guessing they are supposed to be identical, so in theory it wouldn't matter which list you use. But in practice, well ...

Lastly, you'll notice that the response I get for most of these are `GET 304` which is the HTTP status code for "Not Modified".

> **304 Not Modified**
>
> Indicates that the resource has not been modified since the version
> specified by the request headers If-Modified-Since or If-None-Match.
> In such case, there is no need to retransmit the resource since the
> client still has a previously-downloaded copy.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Or in other words, I already have that dependency, so the package (`tgz`) was not downloaded for me. For you it could be different.

You'll notice that for the `content-type` module, I did not previously have this dependency on my local system. So it was downloaded to ensure all listed dependencies were satisfied.

```
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/content-type 412ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/content-type/-/content-type-1.0.5.tgz 59ms
```

`npm` ensures that **ALL** the dependencies are correctly downloaded and available, before the `express` module can be used.

So there you have it! Please let me know if I missed anything. Obviously I only summarized my quick research/investigation, but I'll definately be going into a much deeper investigation of all this. I'm interested in creating my own private registry  for myself.